# Negative dp when using Configurator in AndroidPlot

Tags: androidplot

I'm using AndroidPlot and have an issue trying to use a negative value in an XML file.
I'm having this property:

`androidPlot.graphWidget.domainLabelHorizontalOffset="-20dp"`

And when trying to configure it, it crashes...

`Configurator.configure(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), gapFormatter, R.xml.gap_formatter);`

The bug seems to come from PixelUtils that uses this pattern:

`private static final Pattern DIMENSION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\s*(\d+(\.\d+))\s([a-zA-Z]+)\s*$");`

I think that adding a simple "-?" behind the "^" should resolve the problem, but I have many static final method and their classes to override...

`private static final Pattern DIMENSION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\-?\s*(\d+(\.\d+))\s([a-zA-Z]+)\s*$");`

Does someone have a simple workaround to put some negative dip, please ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no workaround available in 0.6.1.  [A bug report](https://androidplot.jira.com/browse/ANDROIDPLOT-194) has been created to track the problem and will be resolved in the next release.  I'll update this answer once the fix is available.